# AngularJS ng-checked not updating with model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On my page I have brand A and Brand B. By clicking on one, I display a filtered list of address types, and clicking on one of those then filters locations.

When I click on brand A, I save an object of the checked items and overwrite with brand B's list. When I click back to Brand A, the location list is filtered correctly, but the address types are not being checked, even though they exists in the array.

FYI, md-checkbox is an Angular Material checkbox.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul >
    <li id="brandA" ng-click="setBrand(0)" ng-class="{'brandSelected': brand == 0}">
        </span>Brand A</span>

    </li>

    <li id="brandB" ng-click="setBrand(1)" ng-class="{'brandSelected': brand == 1}">
        </span>Brand B</span>
    </li>
</ul>

<div ng-repeat="item in addressTypes | filter : filterAddressTypeByBrand">
    <md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-checked="exists(item)" ng-click="toggle(item)" ng-model="item.selected">
    {{ item.desc }}
    </md-checkbox>
</div>
```

Here is an extract of my controller:

```
$scope.addressTypesSelected = [];
$scope.addressTypesSelectedBrandA = [];
$scope.addressTypesSelectedBrandB = [];


$scope.toggle = function (item) {
    var idx = $scope.addressTypesSelected.indexOf(item);
    if (idx > -1) $scope.addressTypesSelected.splice(idx, 1);
    else $scope.addressTypesSelected.push(item);
};
$scope.exists = function (item) {
    return $scope.addressTypesSelected.indexOf(item) > -1;
};


$scope.setBrand = function (val) {
    $scope.brand = val;
    $scope.addressTypesSelected = [];

    if ($scope.brand == 1) {
        $scope.addressTypesSelectedBrandB = [];
        $scope.addressTypesSelectedBrandB = angular.copy($scope.addressTypesSelected);

        $scope.addressTypesSelected = angular.copy($scope.addressTypesSelectedBrandA);
    } else {
        $scope.addressTypesSelectedBrandA = [];
        $scope.addressTypesSelectedBrandA = angular.copy($scope.addressTypesSelected);

        $scope.addressTypesSelected = angular.copy($scope.addressTypesSelectedBrandB);
    }

    $scope.filterDealers($scope.dealers);
}
```

What needs to be done to get the checkboxes checked when switching between brands?

UPDATE 1.

I've added ng-model="item.selected" to md-checkbox. This seemed to do the trick. However, if I check a box on Brand A, then click on Brand B, then click Brand A, the checkbox remains checked. If I continue and click on Brand B then click again on Brand A, the checkbox is unchecked, yet the value in the model is set to true.

Comment: Sorry, it's an Angular Material checkbox. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.checkbox

Comment: You don't have `ng-model` on that checkbox. That's the normal way to bind to scope

Comment: Added ng-model, but it still doesn't quite work. See Update above.

Comment: can you recreate a case : http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3azh04mj/3/